# mysql select count of distinct rows based on newest date and insert into another table

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sql-insert

As the subject states, I have a table with multiple rows per user and I need to get a count of all rows for each user with the data from the row with the oldest date AND then insert one new row, with the count value, into another table.

I am importing an attendance list CSV file into a temporary table...which is working fine.  But now I need to process all of the individual records into a single summary record to be added to the final table.

```
tempTable:
id   email      tDate        cValue  col4    col5   col6
==========================================================
1    a@a.com    2021-01-01    1      foo     bar    foobar
2    b@b.com    2021-01-02    1      bar     foo    barfoo      
3    a@a.com    2021-02-01    1      foo     bar    foobar
4    c@c.com    2021-01-15    1      bah     hab    bahhab
5    d@d.com    2021-02-15    1      hab     bah    habbah
5    b@b.com    2021-03-01    1      bar     foo    barfoo
6    a@a.com    2021-04-01    1      foo     bar    foobar
7    d@d.com    2021-03-01    1      hab     bah    habbah

newTable (with newest date)
id   email      tDate        cValue  col4    col5   col6
==========================================================
1    a@a.com    2021-04-01    3      foo     bar    foobar
2    b@b.com    2021-03-01    2      bar     foo    barfoo
3    c@c.com    2021-01-15    1      bah     hab    bahhab
4    d@d.com    2021-03-01    2      hab     bah    habbah
```

I think the below works (I have tested the `select` part, but not the full `insert` yet), but I don't know how to process the GROUP BY `email` based on tDate being the oldest or newest.  I haven't decided yet where the oldest or newest data should be the final record - but I still need to know how to grab by the date.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (email,tDate,cValue,col4,col5,col6) 
SELECT 
   email,
   tDate,
   COUNT(*) as  tValue,
   col4,
   col5,
   col6 
FROM tempTable 
GROUP BY email ;
```

When I do an `ORDER BY tDate DESC` - it is simply ordering the output, not actually ordering the records before the GROUP BY.

Comment: Because you only `GROUP BY email`, MySQL does not know which `tDate` to return (I am taking about a default 8.0x installation)  Should it return the `MIN(tDate)`, or the `MAX(tDate)` , or use any other [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) ?  (The same applies to col4,col5 and col6)  (See the error "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.tempTable.tDate' which is not ..... GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by": [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/hbXGfUPQ))

Comment: @Luuk - odd.  I ran the query on my own db and it worked.   I didn't get the error listed in your DBFiddle.  I wonder why?  This worked:  `INSERT INTO newTable (email,tDate,cValue,col4,col5,col6) SELECT email,MIN(tDate),COUNT(*) as  tValue,col4,col5,col6 FROM tempTable GROUP BY email ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luuk has already explained, this is a non-deterministic query and you should read about [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is a good thing and should be enabled.

The idea is to get the MAX tDate and COUNT per email and then use that to join back to the original table values -

```
SELECT t1.email, t1.tDate, t2.cnt AS cValue, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6
FROM tempTable t1
JOIN (
    SELECT email, MAX(tDate) AS maxDate, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM tempTable
    GROUP BY email
) t2 ON t1.email = t2.email AND t1.tDate = t2.maxDate;
```

Alternatively, if using MySQL 8 you can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), specifically [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to assign row numbers per partition ordered by tDate descending and then select where row_number = 1

```
SELECT email, tDate, cValue, col4, col5, col6
FROM (
    SELECT
        email,
        tDate,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS cValue,
        col4,
        col5,
        col6 ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY tDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM tempTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY email ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to both @nnichols and @Luuk for clueing me into the use of MIN/MAX in the query.  I should have thought of it myself but...well, didn't.  lol.

Just using the `MIN` or `MAX` gave me what I was looking for....but with a caveat.  See caveat noted below.  In my case though, I don't have to worry about the caveat so simply doing the `MIN/MAX` in my current query is all I needed.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (email,tDate,cValue,col4,col5,col6) 
SELECT 
   email,
   MAX(tDate),
   COUNT(*) as  tValue,
   col4,
   col5,
   col6 
FROM tempTable 
GROUP BY email ;
```

Outputted:

```
newTable (with newest date)
id   email      tDate        cValue  col4    col5   col6
==========================================================
1    a@a.com    2021-04-01    3      foo     bar    foobar
2    b@b.com    2021-03-01    2      bar     foo    barfoo
3    c@c.com    2021-01-15    1      bah     hab    bahhab
4    d@d.com    2021-03-01    2      hab     bah    habbah
```

Or with `MIN`:

```
newTable (with newest date)
id   email      tDate        cValue  col4    col5   col6
==========================================================
1    a@a.com    2021-01-01    3      foo     bar    foobar
2    b@b.com    2021-01-02    2      bar     foo    barfoo
3    c@c.com    2021-01-15    1      bah     hab    bahhab
4    d@d.com    2021-02-15    2      hab     bah    habbah
```

***CAVEAT***: the `MAX(tDate)` being selected does not mean the rest of the columns being selected are also from the same row.  I saw instances where if col4 for the same email address had different values, that the `MIN/MAX(tDate)` returned the same col4 value even though the returned `tDate` was different each time.

If I truly needed all the data from the same tDate row (MIN or MAX), then I would need to do query more like @nnichols answered with.

Comment: I am glad you achieved what you needed. You really should enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on your MySQL instance. It will help you write valid SQL and avoid strange bugs due to non-deterministic queries.